# Binary parsing lookahead

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am using [binary-bits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-bits) for parsing a binary structure.
But I need a lookahead mechanism since it will condition the way I parse the structure.

For instance:

- If the bit`n+6` is 1 I should read the bits `[n .. n+5]` as a whole value.
- If the bit `n+6` is 0 I should read the bits `[n .. n+4]` as a whole value and the bit `n+5` is being discard

Using the [binary-bits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-bits) library there is no mechanism to help do that. Do you have any suggestion to cleanly do that? Or should I use an other library for parsing bits?

Comment: Do you mean _only_ the bits `n` and `n+5` or do you mean the inclusive range `[n .. n+5]`?

Comment: Why not parse the whole value, apply a mask to check `n+6` bit, then mask the whole value depending on that result.

Comment: Think about it. Does a CPU have a parser? No. As bheklilr said use a mask. All the binary encoded data I know of is not parsed but understood using bit mask. You parse human input, not binary data. The purpose of binary encoded data is to avoid the overhead of parsing. You should edit the question and take the reference to parsing out.

Comment: Typically the reason for the flag bit being after the data is because of historical reasons. At first bits 0-5 were used then they wanted to add another mode or something, so they used bit 6 as a flag and then used bits 0-4 for the new mode or something. If you look at the history of the specific data I would not be surprised if you find something similar.

Comment: I would give an answer, but I don't do Haskell and to do the answer justice is should give a working Haskell example. If someone it waiting for me to give an answer don't as I will not be giving one.